# Webpack generates unexpected JS file when building CSS

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, mini-css-extract-plugin

When building SASS/SCSS files directly with webpack 4 in combination with the MiniCssExtractPlugin 2 files are emitted: the expected CSS output but also a JavaScript file.

I use the CSS files as entry points (not importing them from JS source). I'm not sure what part of the chain is responsible for this behavior because especially for SASS quite some loaders must be used. In order to reproduce the problem, I created this repo: https://github.com/jneuendorf/webpack4-mini-css-extract-plugin

According to some other stackoverflow questions one should import the CSS file from within JavaScript but these answers may not be up to date anymore. See

- [Webpack generates js files with css / scss files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56937912/)
- [Webpack bundle generates additional JS file along with CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775062/)
- [Webpack building both css and js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977879/)

Is this still the recommended or is there also a clean webpack-style version to solve the problem for CSS entry points?

Comment: I recommend reading the documentation for what it is https://webpack.js.org/concepts If you don't want to click, I'll give it here "At its core, webpack is a static module bundler for modern JavaScript applications. ..." I do not see there information about compiling scss or other things is a tool for js. If you want to compile only scss to css use only node-sass. Just use the command line in this way: `node-sass style.scss style.css`. I recommend going to github and looking for `webpack boilerplate` there. You have many bugs in your code, like old dependencies, the entry should contain a js.

Comment: Hey @GrzegorzT. thanks for the quick reply. What kind of bugs do you mean - what are _old_ dependencies? Feel free to add issues to the repo. I am aware that webpack is a JS build tool but the repo is only a minimal example to reproduce the problem. In reality there are lots of JS and CSS entries. After some research I found https://github.com/fqborges/webpack-fix-style-only-entries which addresses the problem and links 2 issues from webpack and the mini-css-extract-plugin. So apparently lots of people have that problem but the community is aware and will get rid of the problem with webpack 5